# timstamp keep changing in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which has 50+ data. And there I show the timestamp difference.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    long mtime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(System.currentTimeMillis())-TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(Long.parseLong(time));
                    if (mtime<60){
                        holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime)+ " mins");
                        if (mtime==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(1+ " min");
                        else if (mtime<1){
                            holder.timestamp.setText("Just Now");

                        }
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(mtime+ " mins");
                    }
                    else if (mtime>60 && mtime<1440){
                        if (mtime/60==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/60)+ " hour");
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/60)+ " hours");
                    }
                    else if (mtime>1440&&mtime<10080){
                        if (mtime/1440==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/1440)+ " day");
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/1440)+ " days");
                    }else if(mtime>10080&&mtime<3679200){
                        if (mtime/10080==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/10080)+ " week");
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/10080)+ " weeks");

                    }else if(mtime>3679200){
                        if (mtime/3679200==1)
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/3679200)+ " year");
                        else
                            holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(mtime/3679200)+ " years");
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }

                h.postDelayed(this,1000);
            }
        },1000);
```

It works fine. But when I scroll the recyclerview it keeps changing the timestamp with timestamp of other recyclerview items.

[Timestamp flash gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0ci8.gif)

Comment: You probably want to store `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a value outside of your `loop`

Comment: It's still repeating other's value @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 0):

yes, because you are using `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed()`.  Why you use `Handler` here? the `RecyclerView Adapter` callbacks are called in the UI thread already.

As I see in your code, each time you scroll, the timestamp will be displayed after 1s. If you scroll fast (actually you always do), 1s later, your row view is already reused and displays another item.

Therefore, to solve your issue, you need to remove the `handler` in your code.

Comment: What should I use for this situation for repeating each 1 sec?